# jquery check validity of single element

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a number input field and I'm trying to use jquery to check if the value in there is valid. I can do it in standard javascript/html5 using

```
// html
<input type="number" id="numField" min="50"/>

// javascript
document.getElementById('numField').validity.valid
```

And this works.

With jquery, I've seen how to validate a whole form, but this element is not inside a form (its value is just retrieved as part of an ajax method).

Is there a jquery equivalent of the validity check?

Comment: If it works using javascript, why are you looking for a jquery equivalent? BTW, as jquery is javascript, where is your issue here? I don't get it. Syntax using jquery is just: `$('#numField')[0].validity.valid`

Comment: I guess you could use `$('#numField')[0].validity.valid`, which is jquery-esque; besides that, I am not aware of any jquery equivalent.

Comment: I just thought there might be a slightly shorter syntax

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
$('#numField')[0].validity.valid
```

I know this is old question but maybe it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score -3):

You should check http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/

It doesnt require a form, just a container id

Comment: This looks like custom validation. I'm trying to use standard html5 validation.